# How Solve error in Webview Browser Android Application?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, webview

I m New in Android. I'm trying to build a simple Web view Browser android application. This Application is important for me.But the application is not opening and is crashing.There are many errors in log cat.How to solve this error. please any programmer help me. Thank you

log error txt

```html
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ronny.yesjarweb/com.ronny.yesjarweb.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3377)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3249)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3225)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:275)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:265)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1887)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:220)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:105)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:81)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at com.ronny.yesjarweb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-14 13:31:03.922: E/AndroidRuntime(901):  ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.java

```js
package com.example.package;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public class MainActivity
  extends ActionBarActivity
{
  private static final View activity_main = null;
private static final int exit = 0;
public static File localFile2 = null;
Toast toast;
  WebView webview;
private int yesjar_web;
private int main;
private int refresh;
private int back;
private int forward;
  
  public String getFileName(String paramString)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException
  {
    return URLDecoder.decode(paramString.substring(1 + paramString.lastIndexOf('/')), "UTF-8");
  }
  
  @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "NewApi"})
  protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(activity_main);
    this.webview = ((WebView)findViewById(yesjar_web));
    this.webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
      private CharSequence app_name;

 public void onProgressChanged(WebView paramAnonymousWebView, int paramAnonymousInt)
      {
        MainActivity.this.setTitle("Loading...");
        MainActivity.this.setProgress(paramAnonymousInt * 100);
        if (paramAnonymousInt == 100) {
          MainActivity.this.setTitle(app_name);
        }
      }
    });
    this.webview.setLayerType(1, null);
    ChildBrowserClient localChildBrowserClient = new ChildBrowserClient();
    this.webview.setWebViewClient(localChildBrowserClient);
    WebSettings localWebSettings = this.webview.getSettings();
    this.webview.setInitialScale(1);
    localWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    localWebSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    localWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    this.webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    this.webview.setId(5);
    this.webview.setInitialScale(0);
    this.webview.requestFocus();
    this.webview.requestFocusFromTouch();
  }
  
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu)
  {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(main, paramMenu);
    return true;
  }
  
  public boolean onKeyDown(int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent)
  {
    if ((paramInt == 4) && (this.webview.canGoBack()))
    {
      this.webview.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(paramInt, paramKeyEvent);
  }
  
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem paramMenuItem)
  {
    int i = paramMenuItem.getItemId();
    if (i == refresh)
    {
      String str = this.webview.getUrl().toString();
      this.webview.loadUrl(str);
      return true;
    }
    if (i == back) {
      this.webview.goBack();
    }
    for (;;)
    {
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(paramMenuItem);
    }
  }
  
  public class ChildBrowserClient
    extends WebViewClient
  {
    public ChildBrowserClient() {}
    
    public void onPageFinished(WebView paramWebView, String paramString)
    {
      super.onPageFinished(paramWebView, paramString);
    }
    
    public void onPageStarted(WebView paramWebView, String paramString, Bitmap paramBitmap)
    {
      super.onPageStarted(paramWebView, paramString, paramBitmap);
    }
    
    @SuppressLint({"InlinedApi", "NewApi"})
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView paramWebView, String paramString)
    {
      boolean bool = true;
      String str1 = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(paramString);
      DownloadManager localDownloadManager = null;
      DownloadManager.Request localRequest = null;
      if (str1 != null)
      {
        String str2 = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(str1);
        if ((str2 != null) && ((str2.toLowerCase().contains("video")) || (str1.toLowerCase().contains("mov")) || (str1.toLowerCase().contains("mp3")) || (str1.toLowerCase().contains("3gp"))))
        {
          localDownloadManager = (DownloadManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService("download");
          localRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(paramString));
        }
      }
      try
      {
        File localFile1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MainActivity.this.getFileName(paramString));
        localFile2 = localFile1;
      }
      catch (UnsupportedEncodingException localUnsupportedEncodingException)
      {
        for (;;)
        {
          localUnsupportedEncodingException.printStackTrace();
          File localFile2 = null;
        }
      }
      localRequest.setDescription("Downloading from YesJar Web");
      localRequest.setNotificationVisibility(1);
      localRequest.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(localFile2));
      localDownloadManager.enqueue(localRequest);
      bool = false;
      if (bool) {
        paramWebView.loadUrl(paramString);
      }
      Log.v("blank", paramString.toString());
      return bool;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(activity_main);
```

**or**

```
findViewById(R.id.yesjar_web)
```

instead of

```
findViewById(yesjar_web)
```